# BRACKETS removed by upgrade to 17.04 and now I can't install it

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies

I had Ubuntu 16.04 but when I upgraded it to 17.04, during the process brackets editor was removed, and now I can't install it.

```
$ sudo apt install brackets 

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... 
Done You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  brackets : 
   Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installable 
  teamviewer:i386 : 
   Depends: libjpeg62:i386 but it is not installable 
   Depends: libxtst6:i386 but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. 
Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Comment: DO you have the brackets `ppa` installed

Comment: please [edit] your question and post the full output of `sudo apt install -f` formatted as code with the `{}` button

Answer (score 1):

To install on Ubuntu 17.04:

1. Add `ppa` and update:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install with:

   ```
   sudo apt install brackets
   ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62671/discussion-on-answer-by-george-brackets-removed-and-cant-install).